# Exposing suspend function vs exposing flow

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In android development, we can expose Kotlin flow or suspend function if we are using Kotlin coroutines. I see in many project that flow is exposed even if the network request is one shot. After that, they use `stateIn` in `viewModels` to create `StateFlow`. What I am wondering is that is there any advantage of exposing flow instead of suspend function even though it is one shot request ? All I can think that flow has intermediate operators which might help.

Comment: What do you mean by "one shot"? From the context I would assume you mean a flow that always emits exactly a single item. But my interpretation of the phrase "one shot" would be different - an operation which we can execute only once.

Comment: I mean like send request and get data and that's it. Also, it means a flow that emits only single item

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit opinion-based, but for me personally using a flow for a single item is an anti-pattern. This is similar to always returning a one-sized list of strings instead of a string directly. It is not that bad for the performance or ease of use, but it may be confusing, because the caller may expect multiple items, they may not be sure if the flow is finite or it runs forever, etc. Behavior of a suspend function is very clear and explicit.

Of course, there are good reasons to use such single-item flows, e.g. if we plan to extend it in the future. However, as a rule of thumb, I would avoid doing this.

Having said that, it is pretty easy to convert from one to another. We can convert a flow to suspend by: `flow.first()`. And we can do the other way around by: `flow { foo() }` or `::foo.asFlow()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your thoughts on this topic and totally agree with you :)

Answer (score 3):

One advantage with a StateFlow of a single item over a suspend function is that the item is then cached, so each collector after the first doesn't need to wait for the item to be fetched again and we don't waste resources fetching it multiple times.

**However**, I still consider it an antipattern. If the above is the behavior you want, the appropriate return type is `Deferred` which is explicitly for a single item and will also cache it. Flows are for multiple items. It's in the name, and they are confusing/misleading if you are expecting the callers to consume a single item.

And you asked specifically about the repo layer exposing a plain Flow, not a StateFlow, so at that level, it's even more of an antipattern because the plain cold flow has no feature benefit over a suspend function.

You mentioned Flow having operators, but all of them besides `map` are pointless for a Flow of a single item. And for a single item that you acquire from a suspend function, the `let` scope function will do the same thing as `map`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your thoughts. I think so too that it is confusing when only single item emitted flow